# Use a variable in a link in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a link in cell B2 to another sheet (e.g. `='[A new sheet]Sheet 1'!$A$1)`. This returns whatever is in cell A1 on that spreadsheet.

What I would like to do is put a variable in a cell and then use that variable as part of the path (using it for version control). e.g in C3 I would put "Version 2". The link would be something like `=CONCATENATE("'[A new sheet]Sheet 1 ",C3,"'!$A$1")` so every time I update cell C3 it would go to that version. I have tried this but it simply returned the text rather than the content of the cell.

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: You can refer to the INDIRECT function: http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/indirect.htm

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `SuperINDIRECTman`!!!  Er, I mean, the `INDIRECT` function.

`INDIRECT` is used to convert a text string into a cell reference. It's very useful when you want to create Data Validation dropdowns that change depending on the choice in another dropdown.

For your example, the formula would be:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[A new sheet]Sheet 1 ",C3,"'!$A$1"))
```

Also, you don't necessarily need to use the `CONCATENATE` function for this; in most cases, you can just use the `&` operator to combine text strings, thus:

```
=INDIRECT("'[A new sheet]Sheet 1 " & $C$3 & "'!$A$1")
```